# How to get which friends I've sent messages to when using Facebook API messenger dialog?

Tags: ios, facebook

My iOS app current uses FBDialogs presentMessageDialogWithParams to send FaceBook messenger messages to friends for a reminder message.

After this method is called, it launches the Messenger App and user is allowed to choose friends to send a preformed message to.  After it's done, goes back to my App.

Are there any way for my App to know which users I've sent messages to?  I've tried in the api Callbacks, but I could not find anything.  Maybe there are some events I could subscribe to?

Comment: No, and why do you need to know who the message was sent to?

Comment: Business Logic requirement

Comment: What is the business logic requirement?

Comment: not sure why you need to know, all I know is I need this requirement done.

Comment: Ok. It is not possible. So I just wanted to know why you needed it because maybe it is possible to solve it in some other way that doesn't require to get the user ids back